# Error al limpiar texbox y combobox en C#

Tags: c#, combobox

hola muy buen dia señores el detalle es el siguiente se que el limpiar un texbox es facil y tambien un combobox, lo que ocurre es que he creado una clase llamada limpiarcombo y texbox. hago la aclaracion esta clase hace un recorrido en los formularios y los groupbox para limpiar texbox y combobox el detalle radica en cuando le doy click al boton donde esta aagregada la funcion limpiar ocurre esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seguida anexo el codigo del formulario...

```
private void Btneliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion();
        string eliminar = "DELETE FROM `productos` WHERE descripcion='"+cmbproducto.Text+"';";
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(eliminar,conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion());
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion().Close();
        MessageBox.Show("el producto fue eliminado");
        conn.clearcombotex limpia = new conn.clearcombotex();
       limpia.BorrarCampos(this, groupBox1);

    }
```

y tambien anexo el codigo de mi clase limpiar...

```
class clearcombotex
{
    public void BorrarCampos(Control control,GroupBox box)
    {
        foreach (var txt in control.Controls)
        {
            if (txt is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)txt).Clear();
            }
            else if (txt is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)txt).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        //el metodo limpia los textbox y combobox que esten en un groupbox
        foreach (var combo in box.Controls)
        {
            if (combo is ComboBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)combo).Clear();
            }
            else if (combo is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)combo).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

el error radica en el metodo limpiar combobox alguien podria explicarme en que me estoy equivocando po mejor dicho cual seria el proceso para poder resolver este dilema

de antemano muchas gracias y buen dia...

Answer (score 0):

Estas preguntando si es un ComboxBox, si te da true luego lo quieres hacer un Cast a otro tipo (TextBox).

```
foreach (var combo in box.Controls)
    {
        if (combo is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)combo).Clear();
        }
        else if (combo is ComboBox)
        {
            ((ComboBox)combo).SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```